# Using a Python module

Tags: python, dictionary, module

I am trying to import the students.py module and call it in another to print out values of the dictionary in that module but it is not working. Where am I going wrong?

Here is students.py

```
def person1():
  student1 = {
  "name": "Joe",
  "major": "Programming",
  "format": "Campus Live"
  }
```

Here is the file am calling that module from

```
import students
x = students.person1("major")
y = students.person1("name")
print(x)
print(y)
```

I would like it to print the major which is programming and name Joe. They are 2 different .py files remember. Am still new to python

Comment: ```person1()``` doesn't take any arguments in students.py but you're giving it one in the other file

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with the use of module imports.  If `student1` is just a dict you don't need to write a function.  You can just write a dict at module level: `person1 = {'name': ...}` and use it lke `students.person1['major']`

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful, to also post the error.

(I am also new to python).

But your person1() is a function, but has no return value.
I think, what you're looking for, is a class.

```
class person():
  def __init__(self, name, major, format_):
    self.name = name
    self.major = major
    self.format_ = format_

p1 = person("John", "Programming", "Campus Live")


print(p1.name)
print(p1.major)
print(p1.format_)
```

this return:

```
John
Programming 
Campus Live
```

Adapted from here:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp

Maybe some other people go a bit more into detail, but maybe this helps you to find the correct answer, you're looking for

EDIT:

Or if you have a list of predefined students, you can go for a (nested) dictionary:

```
students = {
  "student1" : {
  "name": "Joe",
  "major": "Programming",
  "format": "Campus Live"
  },
   "student2" : {
   "name" : "Jane",
   "major" : "Economics",
   "format" : "Offline Campus"}
}

print(students["student1"]["name"])
print(students["student1"]["major"])
print(students["student1"]["format"])
```

best
Christian

Comment: Or this class-wrapper could be used in compination with double-underscore(dunder) str or dunder repr build-in functions to the class. dunder str and dunder repr are called when something tries to print the object like in 
>>> print(personInstance)
This would yield a custom tailored outpout string for each object you create from this class.
Also as rule of thumb: Use dunder str if the result should only be read as string and dunder repr if you want to allow for usage of the data after printing. Usually dunder repr is implemented to give a collection (list/dict) with all params/values.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing values to a function but it doesn't really take arguments right now.
Also you are trying to get any values from a function which doesn't return any values when you call it, so you need to add return keyword with needed value from a dictionary.

So here is the code that will make your function working as you want

```
def person1(name):
  student1 = {
  "name": "Joe",
  "major": "Programming",
  "format": "Campus Live"
  }
  return student1[name]
```

Comment: Apart if persons are named "name", "major" and "format", this would not be working at all. Please edit your answer with working code or remove it.